# Efficient way to count perfect square multiples of $24$ less than $10^6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many positive perfect square less than ${10^6}$ are multiples of 24. I know you can list all the multiples of 24, and compute the square of each of them as you increase the number by 24. But what if the problem requires to be solve in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if a perfect square $N^2$ is a multiple of $24$, then his root $N$ is a multiple of 12.
In fact $2^3\cdot 3 \; \rvert \; N^2$ implies $N^2 = 2^{4} \cdot 3^2 \cdot $ stuff.

So $(12 \cdot k)^2 < 10^6$ $\Rightarrow$ $12k<10^3$

So $$k< \frac{10^3}{12} = \frac{2 \cdot 5^3}{3} \approx 83$$

Specifically the first ones are
$k=1 ; \; (12)^2=144 = 24 \cdot 6$

$k=2 \; ; \; (12\cdot 2)^2 = 576 = 24 \cdot 24$

to $k=83$, $(12\cdot 83)^2 = 992016= 24 \cdot 41334$

Comment: How did you discover this?

Comment: I didn't discover anything. I wrote down what I had and tried to imply something good in terms of <

Comment: I meant your observation

Comment: the "in fact" part is exactly about that. If $N^2 = 24 \cdot k$, then $N = \sqrt{24 \cdot k} = 2\sqrt{6k}$. Since it has to be an integer, $k=6t^2$ for some integer $t$, so $N= 4\cdot 3 \cdot t = 12t$

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to notice that all such numbers are of the form $n=(12k)^2 = 24 \cdot 6 \cdot k^2$. Then the answer is $\lfloor\frac{1000}{12}\rfloor = 83$.

Answer (score 1):

The need to have the factors of $24=2^3\cdot 3$. Since the number must be a perfect square, it has an even number of each factor, so it contains at least $$2^4\cdot 3^2$$ or anything "greater". In the root of the square then, must be at least $$2^2\cdot 3=12$$ or "greater". Since the squares go up to $10^6$, the roots go up to $10^3=1,000$.

So the valid roots are $12,24,36,\ldots$ and the number of them is $$\left\lfloor \frac{1000}{12} \right\rfloor$$

$12$ goes into $120$ and so $960$ and so $996=12\cdot (10\cdot 8+3)=12\cdot 83$. Therefore I find the answer to be $$83$$